# Entity Framework's DbModel: How to map a one to many relationship using a connection table?

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to map via DbModel this relationship present on the database.

```
CREATE TABLE core.Institutes 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    OldID INT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE core.InstitutePlaces
(
    FKInstituteID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES core.Institutes(ID),
    FKPlaceID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES core.Places(ID)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE core.Places
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    FKParentID INT NULL REFERENCES core.Places(ID),
    OldID INT NULL
)
GO
```

on this model

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Place Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Institute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}
```

we're using something like this to do the mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Institutes.Institute>().HasOptional(i => i.Place);
```

but it doesn't work :(

This scenario is perfectly managed by the EDML file, so the problem is only about the mapping.

Comment: I believe in your model for a 1 to * to work, the navigation property needs to be an ICollection<Institute> Institutes {get; set;}, to enable lazy loading, make the property virtual. Here is a good blog on EFCF CPT5 http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/default.aspx

Comment: Thank you but we would like to avoid having a navigation property from the Place to the Institutes because it has no meaning for us to traverse from a Place to its Institutes or to other entities linked to that specific place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will give you (almost) the desired schema with one caveat: Code First does not create a 1:1 relationship in entity splitting scenarios which your desired schema (creating a 1:* association using a join table) is a special case of it.

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Place Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Institute
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? PlaceId { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Institute> Institutes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Institute>().Map(mc =>
        {
            mc.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.Name });
            mc.ToTable("Institutes");
        })
        .Map(mc =>
        {
            mc.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.PlaceId });
            mc.ToTable("InstitutePlaces");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Place>()
                    .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);
    }
}
```

I had to switch off identity generation due to a bug that I explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021742/ef4-code-first-how-to-properly-map-splitting-an-entity-across-multiple-tables/5021957#5021957).

Comment: thank you for your answer!
i didn't think about using the entity split. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could provide a real answer to at least one of your questions :)